# Signing into a different Apple ID for Media and Purchases

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id

I'm signed in to two Apple IDs on my iPhone. I'm signed into iCloud with my personal ID, but my media and purchases for App store use my mom's apple ID. Any apps I download also come up on my mom's phone, and our Apple music seems to be synced as well
I want to sign out of my mom's ID on App store and media and sign in with mine.

Does anyone know if I would lose the apps that I've downloaded on my phone if I do this? I know the purchases cannot be transferred to a different ID, but that's not a problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not lose the apps already installed on your device. These apps will stay installed and registered to the previous ID. You may need to enter the Apple ID used to first install the app after a while when you come to update them and automatic updates will stop working for these apps. You will be prompted for this at the point of updating if this applies — you don't need to remember nor sign out and back in.